# Xcode send multiply parameter to url

Tags: php, iphone, xcode, xcode4

I try to make an signup form in Xcode. I will store the information in my mysql database. But when i send the values to URL in Xcode, the php script can only get the first one. I get no syntax error in Xcode, but I'am still not sure if it's right or not. If you can spot an error in the following code, I will be happy to hear form you.

Xcode:

```
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/login/index.php?email=%@",email.text, "&username=%@", username.text];
```

My php code:

```
<?php
    $email      =   $_GET['email'];
    $username   =   $_GET['username'];
    $sql        =   "INSERT INTO users (email, username) VALUES ('$email', '$username')";
    $qry        =   mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3):

Try to do:

```
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/login/index.php?email=%@&username=%@",email.text, username.text];
```

Comment: Then it put the email value in both email and username variables?

Comment: Put a breakpoint after that string and do - po strURL you will see replaced string

Comment: Is it possible that you will make the example for me?

Comment: `NSString *str1 = @"test@gmail.com";
    NSString *str2 = @"testUser";
    NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/login/index.php?email=%@&username=%@", str1, str2];
    NSLog(@"Replaced str - %@", strURL);`

Comment: Ye it works but now the values are static, and I have no idea what so ever how to make them dynamic? :)

Comment: Replace str1 and str2 with your data (username.text etc)

Comment: Ye i know :) but don't know the syntax. have try this: NSString *str1 = @"email.text"; NSString *str2 = @"username.text";

Comment: AHHH now i get it :D ... THANK YOU SO MUTCH !

Comment: yeah, think you "got" it. You should learn basic of ios development